# Install zip on SteamOS

Tags: apt

How can I install zip on Steam OS (a Debian Wheezy derivative) if my `apt` sources do not have it?

```
# apt-get install zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package zip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'zip' has no installation candidate

# apt-cache show zip
N: Can't select versions from package 'zip' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Answer (score 2):

The package `zip` is purely virtual. What does this means? That any package under `zip` would allow you to use the compressor (I don't know why SteamOS is like that, Debian use a [real package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/zip)). So, instead, you should use `apt-cache depends zip` to find which packages provide the zip package, but I'm sure you would like instead the `unzip` package.

Comment: `apt-cache depends zip` just outputs: `<zip>`, installing `unzip` does not install `zip`. :(

Comment: OK solved by just adding wheezy source and explicitly using that.